# How can I join the result of `ls` as a char separated string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a folder containing the following files:

- File_1.txt
- File_2.txt
- AnotherFile.txt

I want to be able to achieve an output of: `File_1.txt - File_2.txt`

I have tried running:

`ls .\file*.txt | %{$_.Name}`

which returns what I want except on separate lines, how can I join the files returned by a given character (`-` in this example)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-join` operator:

```
(ls file*) -join ' - '
```

If you need more control about the individual items being joined here, just amend the pipeline appropriately:

```
(ls file* | select -Expand Basename) -join ' - '
```

Comment: Couldn't get any simpler than that! tnx.

Answer (score 0):

i'd do:

ls .\file*.txt | Foreach { $output = $output  + $_ + ' - '}

Comment: tnx Steban, but I am getting `Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'` when I run it.

Comment: yep, i just updated my posting. forgot the "Foreach" instead of %
i am still a beginner in PS ;)

Comment: This would work if you initialized `$output = ''` in the beginning, but even so, it would also append `" - "` after every element instead of doing a join.