# How can I join the result of Get-ChildItem by a given character in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33077547/1226568) on how to `join` the result of `ls` which I tried to use for the result returned by `Get-ChildItem` but to no luck.

The command I am trying to `join` the result of (by let's say `-`) is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter bin -Recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer} | gci -Filter *test*.dll -Recurse | select {$_.FullName}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the `FullName` property so you can join strings instead of objects:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter bin -Recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer} | gci -Filter *test*.dll -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName) -join ' - '
```

Comment: Perfect! Works flawlessly :-)

Comment: I just realized that when I run this the `Full Path` is not included it only returns the file name, any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out, all I had to do was to remove the `$_.`